# udp android server over wifi

Tags: android, sockets, udp

I have made a program which is a server Android for receiving an UDP Packets from a C program client over wifi, but actually the problem is that I can only connect my phone to my PC client through USB cable in order to run my application in my phone .
So as I'm newbie in Android world, I would ask you to guide me on how to set the connection via wifi without using the cable ?

Help !

this is my server code :

```
package com.example.server_android;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Server_Android extends Activity{

    private final static int SERVER_PORT = 1234;
    public final static int RECEIVING_TIMEOUT_SERVER = 3000;
    DatagramSocket socket;
    DatagramPacket packetOut;
    DatagramPacket packetIn;
    byte[] DataIn;
    byte[] DataOut;

    /*Android widgets*/
    TextView text;
    EditText edit;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_server_android);
        //text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        text =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);   
        text.setText("");

        /* Thread for receiving Data from CLient */
        new Thread(new Receiver()).start();
            try {   
        Thread.sleep(500);
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
            Log.e("UDP", "UDP receive failed!");
        }
    }

    public class Receiver implements Runnable{

        public void run(){

            try {

                while(socket != null && !socket.isClosed()){

            DataOut = new byte[1024];
//          InetAddress fromaddress = InetAddress.getByName("10.4.0.11");
            socket = new DatagramSocket(SERVER_PORT);
            socket.setSoTimeout(RECEIVING_TIMEOUT_SERVER);
            packetIn = new DatagramPacket(DataOut,DataOut.length);          

            socket.receive(packetIn);
            text.append("source port :" + packetIn.getPort() + "\n");
            text.append("source address :" + packetIn.getAddress().toString() + "\n");
            Log.d("UDP", "Packet receveid");        
            String message = new String(packetIn.getData());
            text.append(message +"\n"+ packetIn.getPort() +"\n"+ packetIn.getAddress().toString());
            Log.d("UDP", "le message reçu");
            Log.d("Message : ", "" + message);          
            }
            }
            catch(UnknownHostException exc) {
                System.out.println("Destinataire inconnu");
            }
            catch(SocketException exc) {
                System.out.println("Probleme d'ouverture de la socket");
            }
            catch(IOException exc) {
                System.out.println("Probleme sur la reception du message");
            }
            }
        }

}
```

and my client code : 
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
#include "biblio.h"

#define portnumber 1234
int
main(int argc,
     char **argv)
{
//_________Seting_Destination_IP_adress____________________

in_addr_t ipAddress= inet_addr("10.4.0.156");

//---- create UDP socket ----
int udpSocket=socket(PF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0);
if(udpSocket==-1)
  { perror("socket"); exit(1); }

struct sockaddr_in toAddr;
int lenght = sizeof(toAddr);


// ... allowing broadcast (optional)
int on=1;
    if(setsockopt(udpSocket,SOL_SOCKET,SO_BROADCAST,&on,sizeof(int))==-1)
    { perror("setsockopt"); exit(1); }

int s;
for(;;)
  {
  //---- read next line on standard input ----   
  char msg[0x100];
  char *buffer = malloc(100);   
  if(!fgets(msg,0x100,stdin)) { break; } 
  //---- send message to the specified destination/port ----
  bzero(&toAddr,lenght);    
  toAddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
  toAddr.sin_port=htons(portnumber);
  toAddr.sin_addr.s_addr=ipAddress;
  s = sendto(udpSocket,msg,strlen(msg),0,(struct sockaddr *)&toAddr,lenght);
    printf("Destination address is %s -- port is : %d ",inet_ntoa(toAddr.sin_addr),ntohs(toAddr.sin_port));
  if( s == -1)  
  { perror("sendto"); exit(1); } 
}

//---- close UDP socket ----
close(udpSocket);
return 0;
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

This is the log file :

```
 08-20 10:07:56.885: D/libEGL(22622): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
    08-20 10:07:56.890: D/libEGL(22622): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
    08-20 10:07:56.895: D/libEGL(22622): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
    08-20 10:07:56.900: D/(22622): Device driver API match
    08-20 10:07:56.900: D/(22622): Device driver API version: 10
    08-20 10:07:56.900: D/(22622): User space API version: 10 
    08-20 10:07:56.900: D/(22622): mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Mon Mar  5 09:47:55 KST 2012 
    08-20 10:07:56.925: D/OpenGLRenderer(22622): Enabling debug mode 0
    08-20 10:08:05.555: W/dalvikvm(22622): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a2d1f8)
    08-20 10:08:05.570: E/AndroidRuntime(22622): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-1053
    08-20 10:08:05.570: E/AndroidRuntime(22622): android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
    08-20 10:08:05.570: E/AndroidRuntime(22622):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4039)
    08-20 10:08:05.570: E/AndroidRuntime(22622):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:709)
    08-20 10:08:05.570: E/AndroidRuntime(22622):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12675)
    08-20 10:08:05.570: E/AndroidRuntime(22622):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12675)
    08-20 10:08:05.570: E/AndroidRuntime(22622):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12675)
    08-20 10:08:05.570: E/AndroidRuntime(22622):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12675)
    08-20 10:08:05.570: E/AndroidRuntime(22622):    at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:268)
    08-20 10:08:05.570: E/AndroidRuntime(22622):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:12675)
    08-20 10:08:05.570: E/AndroidRuntime(22622):    at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6773)
    08-20 10:08:05.570: E/AndroidRuntime(22622):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3306)
    08-20 10:08:05.570: E/AndroidRuntime(22622):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3162)
    08-20 10:08:05.570: E/AndroidRuntime(22622):    at android.widget.TextView.append(TextView.java:2822)
    08-20 10:08:05.570: E/AndroidRuntime(22622):    at android.widget.TextView.append(TextView.java:2812)
    08-20 10:08:05.570: E/AndroidRuntime(22622):    at com.example.test_udp.MainActivity$Receiver.run(MainActivity.java:70)
    08-20 10:08:05.570: E/AndroidRuntime(22622):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
    08-20 10:08:05.790: D/OpenGLRenderer(22622): Flushing caches (mode 0)
    08-20 10:08:06.325: D/OpenGLRenderer(22622): Flushing caches (mode 1)
    08-20 10:13:05.715: I/Process(22622): Sending signal. PID: 22622 SIG: 9
```

Comment: this is my server code :

Comment: Can you do a ping from your PC to your mobile phone? and also, can you use the navigator in your mobile thru Wifi and connect to a Internet web? If the answer is yes then there nothing else you can do. Otherwise check your mobile Wifi connection and make sure it is connected to the correct access point/router. Are you sure the mobile IP is 10.4.0.156 when connected via Wifi?

Comment: Yes I did a ping and every thing work fine and the IP 10.... is the mobile IP when it's connected via Wifi...

Comment: Your question "I would ask you to guide me on how to set the connection via Wifi without using the cable?" and you say it is connected, now, what other question do you have? Other possible problem could be the PC's firewall not letting you get thru to that port.

Comment: I want to know why when I take off the cable the application doesn't respond?

Comment: So what exactly is your programming question?  Stack Overflow is a place for asking questions about specific problems with programming.

Comment: My programming question is what should I change or change/modify or add to have a data transmission over wifi between my PC and Android device?

Comment: In fact when I send a request from client to Android server whether I use cable to run my serve or not, I got a pop up telling me : "Application has been stopped" it seems that the receive method block the reception of messages and it's the responsible for this crash ! help please I am a newbie in Android and I'm looking for the answer for 3 days without any real solution.

Comment: In wireshark I have destination unreachable(port unreachable)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that when connected thru a cable this program works? Then we do not need to check the code, but taking a look I see that in the run method of your thread, the very first line of code says: `while (socket != null && !socket.isClosed())` which both happen to be true just the way the code is written. So I doubt that it works with Wifi or with cable.

I think you should change the thread's code like this:

```
public void run()
{
    try
    {
        socket = new DatagramSocket(SERVER_PORT);
        socket.setSoTimeout(RECEIVING_TIMEOUT_SERVER);
        DataOut = new byte[1024];
        // InetAddress fromaddress = InetAddress.getByName("10.4.0.11");
        packetIn = new DatagramPacket(DataOut, DataOut.length);
        // keep receiving packets, until keepOn set to false
        while (keepOn)
        {
           socket.receive(packetIn);
           text.append("source port :" + packetIn.getPort() + "\n");
           text.append("source address :" + packetIn.getAddress().toString() + "\n");
           Log.d("UDP", "Packet receveid");        
           String message = new String(packetIn.getData());
           text.append(message +"\n"+ packetIn.getPort() +"\n"+ packetIn.getAddress().toString());
           Log.d("UDP", "le message reçu");
           Log.d("Message : ", "" + message);          
        }
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException exc)
    {
        System.out.println("Destinataire inconnu");
    }
    catch (SocketException exc)
    {
        System.out.println("Probleme d'ouverture de la socket");
    }
    catch (IOException exc)
    {
        System.out.println("Probleme sur la reception du message");
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I did what you say but nothing has changed !